# How can I get equivalent functionality across all iterations of a programmatically created series of UILabel objects

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

Advaced Question: How can I get equivalent functionality across all iterations of a programmatically created series of UILabel objects in UIView (to function across CGIntersect with a second series of UILabels)?

Can all instances of a programmatically created UILabel series possess the equivalent title (self.MYUILABEL) and retain equivalent functionality?

I made a series of equivalently classed UILabels programmatically with a for loop,  but only the last made instance of UILabel is assigned the UILabel title.

How can I get equivalent functionality across all iterations of a programmatically created series of UILabel objects in  UIView?

The goal is to get one series of UILabels to be moved by touch to a second series of UILabels.

Here is how I made the UILabels (which act as goal zones) in my view.

```
for (int i=0;i<characterCount ;i++){
    self.myBottomLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((i*60.0)+10, 200.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    self.myBottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myBottomLabel.text= [myword objectAtIndex:i];
    self.myBottomLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.myBottomLabel.tag=300+[[letterToNumber objectForKey:[myword objectAtIndex:i]] integerValue];
    [self.view insertSubview: self.myBottomLabel atIndex:(500)];
}
```

When I attempt to use CGRectIntersectsRect using self.myBottomLabel only the last UILabel made will function correctly with the self.myBottomLabel title used by thisCGRect:

```
theReceivingCard = [self.myBottomLabel convertRect:[self.myBottomLabel frame] toView:self.view];
```

Here is almost all of the implementation. Do I need to create multiple CGRects (Which I don't know how to do)? Or is there someway to find exactly what the tag is of these UILabel (which are made interactive when you move a corresponding UILabel over the top of them?)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray* myword=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"h",@"e",@"l",@"l",@"o",nil];

    NSDictionary *letterToNumber;
    letterToNumber = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"0", @"a", 
                      @"1", @"b", 
                      @"2", @"c", 
                      @"3", @"d",
                      @"4", @"e", 
                      @"5", @"f", 
                      @"6", @"g", 
                      @"7", @"h", 
                      @"8", @"i", 
                      @"9", @"j", 
                      @"10", @"k", 
                      @"11", @"l", 
                      @"12", @"m", 
                      @"13", @"n", 
                      @"14", @"o", 
                      @"15", @"p", 
                      @"16", @"q", 
                      @"17", @"r", 
                      @"18", @"s", 
                      @"19", @"t", 
                      @"20", @"u", 
                      @"21", @"v", 
                      @"22", @"w", 
                      @"23", @"x", 
                      @"24", @"y", 
                      @"25", @"z", 
                      nil];    

NSUInteger characterCount = [myword count];

    //moveable
    for (int i=0;i<characterCount ;i++){
        self.myTopLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((i*60.0)+10, 100.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
        self.myTopLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.myTopLabel.text= [myword objectAtIndex:i];
        self.myTopLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.myTopLabel.tag=100+[[letterToNumber objectForKey:[myword objectAtIndex:i]] integerValue];
        [self.view insertSubview: self.myTopLabel atIndex:(1)];
    }

    //receiver
    for (int i=0;i<characterCount ;i++){
        self.myBottomLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((i*60.0)+10, 200.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
        self.myBottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.myBottomLabel.text= [myword objectAtIndex:i];
        self.myBottomLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.myBottomLabel.tag=300+[[letterToNumber objectForKey:[myword objectAtIndex:i]] integerValue];
        [self.view insertSubview: self.myBottomLabel atIndex:(500)];
    }

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self.view hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];

    [[viewYouWishToObtain superview] bringSubviewToFront:viewYouWishToObtain];

    if ([touch view] != viewYouWishToObtain && viewYouWishToObtain.tag >= 100 && viewYouWishToObtain.tag <= 200) {
        if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        }
        return;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self.view hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];

    if ([touch view] == viewYouWishToObtain && viewYouWishToObtain.tag >= 100 && viewYouWishToObtain.tag <= 200) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        viewYouWishToObtain.center = location;      

        theMovingCard = [viewYouWishToObtain convertRect:[viewYouWishToObtain frame] toView:self.view];

        theReceivingCard =  [self.myBottomLabel convertRect:[self.myBottomLabel frame] toView:self.view];

        CGRect theZone = CGRectMake(theReceivingCard.origin.x, theReceivingCard.origin.y,theReceivingCard.size.width*2 , theReceivingCard.size.height*2);
        CGRect theCard = CGRectMake(theMovingCard.origin.x, theMovingCard.origin.y,theMovingCard.size.width*2 , theMovingCard.size.height*2);

            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(theCard, theZone))
            {
                NSLog(@"intersect");
            }
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that right there at the end of all the code, the intersect only functions on the last made UILabel. I need the intersect to work across all of the series of UILabels that act as receivers. Super super super super thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of "how to programmatically create multiple CGRect values for multiple CGIntersects for UIView subset matching" by iteration through a for loop.

This is the complete file.
It is an iOS touch enabled foundation for a card game (like solitaire) or as match game (children's education).

The program makes 10 cards where the top row has to match the bottom row. If the top row card has text equivalent to the bottom row card then the CGIntersect will 'hit' and you can execute any additional methods.

There should be a simpler way to make variable CGRect, but I can't find the answer. If someone can figure out how to NOT use a NSMutableArray and a for-loop to generate the CGrect code, then I would be greatly obliged if you would share.

.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

        @property NSString* currentCard;
        @property NSArray* myWord;
        @property NSString* myCurrentLetter;
        @property NSMutableArray* myMoverMutableArray;
        @property NSMutableArray* myReceiverMutableArray;

    @end
```

.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    {
        int myLetterTagNumber;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ViewController

        @synthesize currentCard = _currentCard;
        @synthesize myWord = _myWord;
        @synthesize myCurrentLetter = _myCurrentLetter;
        @synthesize myMoverMutableArray = _myMoverMutableArray;
        @synthesize myReceiverMutableArray = _myReceiverMutableArray;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self writer];
    }

    -(void)writer{

        self.myWord=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"l",@"i",@"l",@"l",@"y",nil];

        NSUInteger characterCount = [self.myWord count];

        self.myMoverMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:characterCount];
        self.myReceiverMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:characterCount];

        //moveable
        for (int i=0;i<characterCount ;i++){
            UILabel*myTopLabel;
            myTopLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((i*60.0)+10, 100.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
            myTopLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            myTopLabel.text= [self.myWord objectAtIndex:i];
            myTopLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            myTopLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            myTopLabel.tag=100+i;
            [self.myMoverMutableArray addObject:[self.myWord objectAtIndex:i]];
            [self.view insertSubview: myTopLabel atIndex:(100)];
        }

        //receiver
        for (int i=0;i<characterCount ;i++){
            UILabel*myBottomLabel;
            myBottomLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((i*60.0)+10, 200.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
            myBottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            myBottomLabel.text= [self.myWord objectAtIndex:i];
            myBottomLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            myBottomLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            myBottomLabel.tag=300+i;
            [self.myReceiverMutableArray addObject:[self.myWord objectAtIndex:i]];        
            [self.view insertSubview: myBottomLabel atIndex:(300)];
        }
    }

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self.view hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];

        //clipping
        [[viewYouWishToObtain superview] bringSubviewToFront:viewYouWishToObtain];

        myLetterTagNumber = viewYouWishToObtain.tag;
        UILabel * myTempUILabel = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:(myLetterTagNumber)];
        self.myCurrentLetter = myTempUILabel.text;

        NSLog (@"text: %@",myTempUILabel.text);
        NSLog (@"Tag: %d",myLetterTagNumber);

        if ([touch view] != viewYouWishToObtain && viewYouWishToObtain.tag >= 100 && viewYouWishToObtain.tag <= 200) {
            if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self.view hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];

        if ([touch view] == viewYouWishToObtain && viewYouWishToObtain.tag >= 100 && viewYouWishToObtain.tag <= 200) {
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            viewYouWishToObtain.center = location;

            //moving card rec
            CGRect theMovingCard;
            theMovingCard = [viewYouWishToObtain convertRect:[viewYouWishToObtain frame] toView:self.view];
            CGRect themovingRect = CGRectMake(theMovingCard.origin.x, theMovingCard.origin.y,theMovingCard.size.width*2 , theMovingCard.size.height*2);

            NSString *myTempString;
            NSUInteger characterCount = [self.myWord count];

            for (int i=0;i<characterCount ;i++){

                myTempString= [self.myReceiverMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];

                if (myTempString == self.myCurrentLetter){
                    UILabel * mytouchMoveUILabel = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:(i+300)];
                    CGRect theReceivingCard;
                    theReceivingCard =  [mytouchMoveUILabel convertRect:[mytouchMoveUILabel frame] toView:self.view];

                    CGRect spaceToHitRect = CGRectMake(theReceivingCard.origin.x, theReceivingCard.origin.y,theReceivingCard.size.width*2 , theReceivingCard.size.height*2);
                    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(themovingRect, spaceToHitRect))
                    {
                        NSLog (@"Intersect: %d",myLetterTagNumber);
                    }
                }//if
            }//for
            return;
        }
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        // NSLog(@"3");

        CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self.view hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];

        if ([touch view] == viewYouWishToObtain && viewYouWishToObtain.tag >= 100 && viewYouWishToObtain.tag <= 200) {
            return;
        }
    }

                - (void)viewDidUnload
                {
                    [super viewDidUnload];
                    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
                }

                - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
                {
                    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
                    } else {
                        return YES;
                    }
                }

    @end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making a ton of labels in your loop but you only have a pointer to the last one you created, since you assign them all to the same property. I'm not totally clear on the rest of your question but I think you should be adding those labels to an array, and iterating through that array when you are hit testing etc.

Comment: Is there a simple superclass pointer or superclass property for subsets of UIImageView? I need a general class to make a general CGRect so that CGRectIntersectsRect will work. 

This program is just a match program that matches equivalent members of two equivalent sets. In this case {{H}{E}{L}{L}{O}} {{H}{E}{L}{L}{O}} mapped onto UILabels.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying. Why would anything from a superclass help you with here? Like I said, you need to hold your labels in an array and iterate through the array when you are hit testing. At the moment you are only testing the rect of a single view.